# objc_msgSend() with C callback function as argument for code block?

Tags: objective-c, c, core-foundation, objective-c-runtime, exc-bad-access

So I'm trying to call an Objective-C method which has a **callback code block** as an argument.

The Objective-C method (implementation cut for purpose of post)

```
- (void)requestWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL, NSArray*))completionHandler {

    // Implementation ...

    completionHandler(YES, NSArray...);

}
```

The C code (***rsc*** holds an allocated and initiated Class)

```
void callback(id self, SEL _cmd, BOOL success, CFArrayRef array)
{
    printf("BOOM\n");
}

objc_msgSend(rsc, sel_getUid("requestWithCompletionHandler:"), (IMP)callback);
```

From Apple Documentation

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

Also...

> An Objective-C method is simply a C function that take at least two
>   arguments—self and _cmd. For example, given the following function:

```
void myMethodIMP(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    // implementation ....
}
```

> you can dynamically add it to a class as a method (called resolveThisMethodDynamically) like this:

```
class_addMethod([self class], @selector(resolveThisMethodDynamically), (IMP) myMethodIMP, "v@:");
```

However when run I get an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a function pointer as a parameter that's a block type, but blocks are not function pointers. As a simple example, the following code will crash at the second invocation of `takesABlock()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

void function1();
void takesABlock(dispatch_block_t block);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ printf("In a block\n"); function1(); };
    takesABlock(block);
    takesABlock((dispatch_block_t)function1);
}

void function1() {
    printf("In function1\n");
}

void takesABlock(dispatch_block_t block) {
    block();
}
```

So, you need instead to pass an actual block:

```
objc_msgSend(rsc, sel_getUid("requestWithCompletionHandler:"), ^(BOOL aBool, NSArray *anArray){ // block code here });
```

It looks like you are doing something highly dynamic so you may need to find a way to dynamically store the block somewhere for later use. It is an object and can by copied, stored in collections, etc. either in Objective-C with the `-copy` method or in pure C APIs by using the `Block_copy()` function to get a pointer to a heap-allocated block for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it's easier than I first thought. You just pass an actual code block as the argument.

```
objc_msgSend((id)rsc, sel_getUid("requestWithCompletionHandler:"), ^(BOOL success, CFArrayRef array) {
        if (success) {
            printf("BOOM\n");
        }});
```

Comment: Didn't see you'd answered as I was typing! But yes, it's pretty straightforward, glad you found a resolution :)

Comment: Thanks anyway yours gave me a better understanding of the problem. Didn't know about `Block_copy()` either!

Comment: Why use objc_msgSend() at all?

Comment: As you cant access Objective-C methods directly in C, for example UIView drawing. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: `"...useful primarily for developing bridge layers between Objective-C and other languages."` [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)